# Get just PID Number from "ps aux --sort -rss "

Tags: linux, shell, pid

How can I just get the `PID` of the following command:

```
ps aux --sort -rss
```

Thanks

Comment: How is this related to Ruby?

Comment: @Stefan
What is it then, Unix?

Answer (score 2):

```
ps aux --sort -rss | awk '{print $2}'
```

Try this

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you want to avoid using any external tools:

`ps -ax --sort -rss -o pid`

By forgoing u (user-oriented format option) and adding -o pid (user-defined output format - only show pid), you'll get what you need.